# How to add a custom button between UISearch Bar and Cancel Button while a search is enabled in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm using ios 14 SDK for development and I want to add a custom button between UISearchBar and the Cancel button when the search is enabled.

I have checked all attributes in UISearchController and UISearchBar level, but i couldn't find any attribute for doing it. :(

I saw a similar kind of button in the default ios files view, I have attached the screenshot and marked it with a red color box.
Can someone give a clue for doing that? I really appreciate your help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if searchController.isActive {
    searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
} else {
    searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = false
}
searchController.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "imgName"), for: .bookmark, state: .normal)
```

Comment: i have tried with , when i use this code, button will show in side of search bar. Actually, i want to show new button outside of search bar. :(

Comment: ahh ok, I understand. Looks like it only appears in the Files app, didnt find it anywhere else o.O. Didn't find anything in Apple documentation, I am very interested now about how to do this. Maybe the possible solution would be to update the insets of the Bookmark button.